# Sort Issues Returned by GitLab API by Update Timestamp

Tags: api, gitlab

When I do the following requests on my GitLab instance they return identical output:

```
curl -o updated.json https://gitlab.domain.com/api/v3/projects/37/issues?private_token=${GITLAB_TOKEN}&order_by=updated_at
curl -o created.json https://gitlab.domain.com/api/v3/projects/37/issues?private_token=${GITLAB_TOKEN}
```

I would expect the `updated.json` to be ordered by the `updated_at` field in the issue, however they are still ordered by `created_at`.

Am I missing something obvious? The source code has the [`issues.reorder(issuable_order_by => issuable_sort)`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/8-1-stable/lib/api/issues.rb#L81) in it so I would expect them to be correctly sorted?

Comment: You need to quote the URL, otherwise the `&` is used to background the `curl` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the URL needed to be quoted:

```
curl -o updated.json "https://gitlab.domain.com/api/v3/projects/37/issues?private_token=${GITLAB_TOKEN}&order_by=updated_at"
curl -o created.json "https://gitlab.domain.com/api/v3/projects/37/issues?private_token=${GITLAB_TOKEN}"
```